# How to check if table has specific grants before inserting a record in a table?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Scenario: I have a config table which includes meta-data about log tables (e.g. Table_name, table_owner). I want to add a trigger to this config table which essentially checks if the table record that is to be inserted, has the specific grant (delete) if not, then don't allow that to happen. How can I go about this?

Comment: Please show your table definitions, example data, and expected output.  Thanks

Comment: So, if I have `DELETE` privilege on `TABLE_A`, then I can insert a record about `TABLE_A` into the config table and, otherwise, I cannot?

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Yes. Also FYI, Config table is in say user1 and TABLE_A is in user2. I am creating a trigger in user1 whereby records (e.g. TABLE_A) can be inserted only if it has Delete privilege for user1. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it is to forget about triggers but use a `VIEW...WITH CHECK OPTION` to control that no one inserts data they shouldn't.

Suppose your config table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_config 
  ( owner VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    table_name VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
    other_stuff VARCHAR2(500),
    CONSTRAINT my_config_pk PRIMARY KEY ( owner, table_name ) );
```

#### Create a view to handle inserts

The conditions of the view limit it to only include tables on which the current user has `DELETE` privileges.

The `WITH CHECK OPTION` will ensure than no one may use the view to insert or update data that does not satisfy the view.

```
CREATE VIEW my_config_ins_v
AS
SELECT * FROM my_config c
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'user has delete privs'
               FROM   user_tab_privs p
               WHERE  p.owner = c.owner
               AND    p.grantee = user
               AND    p.table_name = c.table_name
               AND    p.privilege = 'DELETE' )
WITH CHECK OPTION;
```

#### Try it out

```
INSERT INTO my_config_ins_v VALUES ('USER_1','TABLE_I_HAVE_ACCESS_TO', 'STUFF');
-- 1 row inserted.

INSERT INTO my_config_ins_v VALUES ('SYS','OBJ$', 'STUFF');
-- ORA-01402: view WITH CHECK OPTION where-clause violation
```

Naturally, for this to be effective, you cannot

```
GRANT INSERT ON my_config TO anyone;  -- don't do this
```

Instead:

```
GRANT INSERT ON my_config_ins_v TO anyone;
```